# How get path as string without leading "slash" in Windows in Dart SDK?

Tags: windows, path, uri, dart

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var path = Platform.script.path;
  print(path);
}
```

Output

```
/C:/Users/user/dart/test/bin/test.dart
```

But I want get

```
C:/Users/user/dart/test/bin/test.dart
```

What is recommended way to get OS specific path ready to use in this OS?

P.S.

If I run test code on different platform I get different result.

So, test.

Runtime: Dart SDK version 1.1.1 (STABLE)

Code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var path = Platform.script.path;
  print(path);
  // From doc: Creates a new file URI from an absolute or relative file path.
  var uri = new Uri.file(path);
  print(uri.path);
}
```

Ubuntu 13.10:

```dart
/home/andrew/dart/test/bin/test.dart
/home/andrew/dart/test/bin/test.dart
```

Windows 7:

```dart
/C:/Users/user/dart/test/bin/test.dart
Breaking on exception: Illegal argument(s): Illegal character in path}
Unhandled exception:
Illegal argument(s): Illegal character in path}
```

This behavior prevent me to write cross-platform code.

Comment: The value of `Platform.script.path` is correctly `/C:/Users/user/dart/test/bin/test.dart`. The URI is the following file URI: `file:///C:/Users/user/dart/test/bin/test.dart`. See [File URIs in Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

This code works on all platforms.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var path = Platform.script.toFilePath();
  print(path);
  var uri = new Uri.file(path);
  print(uri.toFilePath());
}
```

P.S.

Similar exception (`Illegal character in path`) can occurs inside Dart SDK (in some cases) when used scheme ""dart-ext":

```dart
Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Illegal character in path}
#0      Uri._checkWindowsPathReservedCharacters.<anonymous closure> (dart:core/uri.dart:395)
#1      ListIterable.forEach (dart:_collection-dev/iterable.dart:39)
#2      Uri._checkWindowsPathReservedCharacters (dart:core/uri.dart:390)
#3      Uri._toWindowsFilePath (dart:core/uri.dart:1018)
#4      Uri.toFilePath (dart:core/uri.dart:992)
#5      _filePathFromUri (dart:builtin:249)
'package:dart_and_cpp_classes/src/cpp_extension.dart': error: line 3 pos 1: library handler failed
import "dart-ext:cpp_extension";
^
'package:dart_and_cpp_classes/cpp_extension.dart': error: line 3 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:dart_and_cpp_classes/src/cpp_extension.dart';
^
'file:///C:/Users/user/dart/dart_and_cpp_classes/bin/use_cpp_extension.dart': error: line 1 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:dart_and_cpp_classes/cpp_extension.dart';
^
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the path package `import package:path/path.dart`.
I don't have Windows running here so I can't verify anything.

After a brief look I found:

```dart
/// An enum type describing a "flavor" of path.
abstract class Style {
  /// POSIX-style paths use "/" (forward slash) as separators. Absolute paths
  /// start with "/". Used by UNIX, Linux, Mac OS X, and others.
  static final posix = new PosixStyle();

  /// Windows paths use "\" (backslash) as separators. Absolute paths start with
  /// a drive letter followed by a colon (example, "C:") or two backslashes
  /// ("\\") for UNC paths.
  // TODO(rnystrom): The UNC root prefix should include the drive name too, not
  // just the "\\".
  static final windows = new WindowsStyle();

  /// URLs aren't filesystem paths, but they're supported to make it easier to
  /// manipulate URL paths in the browser.
  ///
  /// URLs use "/" (forward slash) as separators. Absolute paths either start
  /// with a protocol and optional hostname (e.g. `http://dartlang.org`,
  /// `file://`) or with "/".
  static final url = new UrlStyle();
```

Comment: You can look at an update of my question. So, package `path` cannot solve this problem.

Comment: I don't see why `path` can't help here. Your windows code still uses `/` when the path documentation says that style `windows` uses `\` and absolute paths start with a drive letter.